# python single quotes around certain parts of strings

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
reclass=""
for x in xrange(1,32):
    if x <=30:
        reclass+="remap"+str(x)+"+"
    else:
        reclass+="remap"+str(x)
print reclass
```

Which prints:

```
remap1+remap2+remap3+remap4+...
```

But I want the string to print:

```
'remap1'+'remap2'+'remap3'+...
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried adding the single quotes in the strings anywhere?

Comment: yes I was trying but I couldnt get it to work with the number.

Comment: FWIW: `'+'.join("'remap%s'" % i for i in range(1, 32))`. I'm really more worried what you're going to do with that odd string though…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

For single-quote to be printed, add single-quotes to the strings. A clean way to format strings is to use `str.format` instead of concatenating multiple strings.

```
reclass=""
for x in xrange(1,32):
    if x <=30:
        reclass+="'remap{}'+".format(x)
    else:
        reclass+="'remap{}'".format(x)
print reclass
```

### Ouput

```
'remap1'+'remap2'+'remap3'+ ...
```

### Improvement

An even better solution is to use `str.join`, this avoids creatintg intermediate strings in the process of generating your final output.

```
reclass = '+'.join(["'remap{}'".format(x) for x in xrange(1, 32)])

print (reclass)
```

Comment: ughh wow okay nice, I was messing with the .format() function but this works will accept

Comment: thanks I appreciate it. why is my question getting so violently downvoted?

Comment: its a simple question I know but I was having trouble :(

Comment: @ziggy question being downvoted is not targeted at the user, it just means that the question has not enough reusability potential. It also does not mean you won't get an answer